# Get field type class in form EventListener

Tags: php, types, symfony, addeventlistener

I'm trying to upgrade my application to Symfony3. In Symfony2 in my EventListener, I have:

```
$typeTitle = $event->getForm()->get('title')->getConfig()->getType()->getName();
```

It returns 'text' and after I can use it to change my field

```
$form->add('title', $typeTitle, array_replace($optionsTitle, array(
    'disabled' => true
)));
```

But Symfony3 attending `TextType::class` in the second parameter. I can write this but I prefer that it remains dynamic.

I tried : `$event->getForm()->get('title')->getConfig()->getType()->getInnerType();` it returns :

> object(Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType)[576]

But I can't use it. Does it exist a function which returns `TextType::class` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Symfony3 the `getName()` method has been removed in favor of its Fully Qualified Class Name (FQCN), so just use `get_class()` function on this to solve it:

```
$type = get_class($event->getForm()->get('title')->getConfig()->getType()->getInnerType());
```